# End characters not being added to a string

Tags: .net, string, vb.net

I'm trying to load a string for a DirectorySearch filter.

```
strFilter = "((objectClass=container)(cn=" & strParameter & "))"
```

It doesn't matter what the end characters are, they are not being added to the string. It always ends up as:

```
strFilter = "((objectClass=container)(cn=" & strParameter
```

This is so frustrating. I can't even add the end brackets subsequently. What is going on? Strings should NOT behave like this!

Comment: Can you please show us some more code before that problematic line?

Comment: They don't... What is inside strParameter? do you check the value of strFilter right after it is set?

Comment: If `strParameter` contains a null-character (char 0) the rest of the string will usually not be rendered by most text editors/viewers, even though it is actually there. Try trimming null-characters from your string and see if it fixes your problem: `strFilter = "((objectClass=container)(cn=" & strParameter.Trim(ChrW(0)) & "))"`.

Comment: That ".Trim(ChrW(0)) " seems to be working. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! I will write that as an answer so that you can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: You ought to do the same in your previous questions as well. :)

Comment: I did know that the NULL character terminated a string, 35 years ago. I'd forgotten! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `strParameter` contains a null-character (char 0) the rest of the string will usually not be rendered by most text editors/text viewers, even though it is actually there. This happens because the null-character is usually used to indicate the end of a string.

Try trimming any null-characters from your string and see if it fixes your problem:

```
strFilter = "((objectClass=container)(cn=" & strParameter.Trim(ChrW(0)) & "))"
```

**More information:**

- [**Null-terminated string - Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

---

If you in the future (for some reason) encounter a null-character in the middle of your string you can try removing all null-characters alltogether:

```
strFilter = "((objectClass=container)(cn=" & strParameter.Replace(ChrW(0), "") & "))"
```